# Get data back from context before commit

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

```
customers customer = GetCustomer();
customer.UserId = userId;
customer.NeedToPayTax = true;
customer.IsApproved = false;
_customerRepository.Create(customer);
```

later on before we do a commit I try to search this new `customer`

```
public int GetUncofirmedCount()
{
    var query = from p in _context.Set<customers>()
                where p.IsApproved == false
                select p;

    return query.Count();
}
```

but the size is always `0`. If I make a commit then I can see correct result. Why? How can I get data back from context even is not already commited?

Comment: Which version of EF?

Comment: Are you using the same instance of your context to save the entity and do your query later?

Comment: _context = unitOfWork.Context as DbContext; so it must be always the same

Comment: Version is EF 6.1.3 (last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code:

```
    _customerRepository.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(Customer) && o => !o.IsApproved)
.Count();
```

or, with newer versions of EF, check out `Local`;

```
_customerRepository.Customers.Local
    .Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(Customer) && o => !o.IsApproved)
    .Count();
```

Comment: why to use ObjectStateManager and not simple _context? Can not be this somehow generic? Can _context do this magic for me?

Comment: Because the `context` queries the DB, that´s the purpose of it. But in later versions of EF you should be able to use the local cache, see update.

Comment: thx for info. But then I need to call this logic in many places, and can not be generic. Maybe can I merge all not approved changes in _context?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of generics you need but you could of course implement a generic method `public T GetAddedEntity<T>()` and change to `typeof(T)` but then again, how would you use `IsApproved` if you don´t know what object you are getting?

Comment: Or you can use the `ChangeTracker`? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: `foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added) {..}`

Comment: with last comment you mean to call it after each Create command?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve in the bigger picture. Simply trying to describe what you can do to get the `Entities` that have not been saved to the database yet. The rest is up to you I´m afraid.